# maven fail build when unit test coverage fails below a pre-configured limit in a multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Can someone let me know how can I fail the build when aggregated unit test coverage falls below a preconfigured limit in a maven multimodule project?

For example, let's say `module1` has 70% of code coverage, `module2` has 100% code coverage, and if 90% coverage is specified, then the build should fail as the average coverage is 85%.

I am using jacoco to generate the code coverage to generate an aggregated `.exec` file containing the coverage data . But as discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/0haFMvGBng0/A4UfH_sjBgAJ) `jacoco:check` works only at the module level.

So it looks like jacoco alone cannot do the job I am looking for. Can someone let me know what other tools I can use on the aggregated `jacoco.exec` file to achieve the job?

**Approaches Tried**

As suggested my @Karol

My project structure is like below

```
main
- module1
- module2
```

In `main.pom` I have added the below section

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <destFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</destFile>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                  <id>merge-execs</id>
                  <phase>pre-site</phase>
                  <inherited>false</inherited>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>merge</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                   <fileSets>
                     <fileSet>
                       <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                       <includes>
                         <include>**/target/*.exec</include>
                       </includes>
                     </fileSet>
                   </fileSets>
                    <destFile>${jacoco.ut.merged.exec}</destFile>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
                  <execution>
                      <id>jacoco-check</id>
                      <phase>verify</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>check</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <rules>
                              <rule>
                                  <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                  <limits>
                                      <limit>
                                          <counter>LINE</counter>
                                          <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                          <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                                      </limit>
                                  </limits>
                              </rule>
                          </rules>
                          <dataFile>${jacoco.ut.merged.exec}</dataFile>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
```

Then on doing `mvn pre-site` I can see the merged exec file is getting created like below

```
[INFO] Loading execution data file /var/code/github/vnera/main/module1/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Loading execution data file /var/code/github/vnera/main/module2/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Writing merged execution data to /var/code/github/vnera/main/target/jacoco_vrni_main.exec
```

But when I am running `mvn jacoco:check@jacoco-check` I am seeing the check getting skipped with the below message

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:check (jacoco-check) @ main ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing classes directory:/var/code/github/vnera/main/target/classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a step in the build with [`jacoco:merge`](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/merge-mojo.html) goal:

> Mojo for merging a set of execution data files (*.exec) into a single file

Then apply [`jacoco:check`](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) on this merged coverage file by pointing to it with `<dataFile>` goal property.

---

Alternatively you could setup [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) with [correct JaCoCo multi module coverage](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/MavenMultiModule) and configure [Quality Gates](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/quality-gates/) to ensure minimum code coverage:

> A quality gate is the best way to enforce a quality policy in your organization. It's there to answer ONE question: can I deliver my project to production today or not?
>
> In order to answer this question, you define a set of Boolean conditions based on measure thresholds against which projects are measured. For example:
>
> - No new blocker issues
> - Code coverage on new code greater than 80%
> - Etc.

Comment: SonarQube will require me to run an external server . I am looking for something simple like what the jacoco:check does for a single module. Is there any other option like this for a multimodule project?

Comment: Check my updated question. The check is still not running.